# What is a simple regular expression to obtain a number

Tags: regex, perl

I have a `$variable= 9.1R999`.
I need a regular expression to obtain a digit before and after '.'. I need 9.1 stored in a new variable `$variable1`.

Answer (score 3):

Use matching with a capture group, assign in list context to get the captured value:

```
my $variable = '9.1R999';
my ($number) = $variable =~ /([0-9]\.[0-9])/;
```

The dot needs to be backslashed to get its literal meaning.

Comment: Thank you Choroba.

Comment: "Thank you" is expressed by accepting/upvoting the answer.